# jquery is executing all function at once

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having a strange problem with jquery (well, I'm kinda new to jquery), but...

I have a form with some elements to be filled...ok
below that (but inside the form tag) I have 3 buttons:

1st:

```
<button name="submit" id="submit">Atualizar Dados</button>
```

It's supposed to send the form

2nd:

```
<button name="del" id="del">Remove nicedit instance</button>
```

It's to remove a nicedit instance from the form.

3nd:

```
<button name="qqq" id="qqq">Q</button>
```

It's just a test to use a fade-in effect on a div.

Well, now I have this four functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
                url: 'admin.php',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function (str) {
             window.location = 'test.php';
                }
              });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    $("#del").click(function(){
             txtDescr.removeInstance('LDescr');
    });

    $("#qqq").click(function(){
             $("#info").fadeIn(1500).delay(5000).fadeOut(1500);
    });
});
```

The problem is that no matter what button I click, the form is submitted....even the qqq button seems to submit the form. I've tried dozens of combinations, I already googled, but I just can't find an answer. Please, can somebody tells me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: add `return false;` at the end of the click function

Comment: Do you have a form tag in your html?

Comment: @Spokey, `return false` calls both `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`, the latter being completely unnecessary in most cases. This makes `return false` dangerous advice, particularly when event delegation is used.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers...already solved...missed the type="button". THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the default type of a `button` element is `submit`, you can set the `type` attribute to `button` or prevent the default action of the event using `preventDefault` method of the event object.

```
<button name="qqq" id="qqq" type="button">Q</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`button` elements are `type="submit"` by default. If you want them to not submit the form, then you need to change them to:

```
<button type="button" ...
```

[From the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-button-type)

> The *missing value default* is the [Submit Button](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-button-type-submit-state) state.

Answer (score 0):

The `button` element is effectively a `<input type="submit" />` element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button for details.

To correct the problem, either add a call to `.preventDefault()` or `return false` (or both) in your click event handlers, or add `type="button"` to your `button` elements, or use `<input type="button" />` instead of a `<button>` element.

Comment: `return false` calls `e.stopPropagation()` as well and can have unexpected consequences in some situations, so it's better to suggest just `e.preventDefault()` in this case since there is no need to prevent event propagation from bubbling up the DOM.  You also might want to point out that the reason his `e.preventDefault()` isn't working is because he failed to pass the event `e` as a parameter in his click handler.

Comment: Thank you everybody, it´s really good to learn something new, but the problem is already solved, at least I tested and works, it was the missing type=button in the buttons on the form. Thanks anyways.